# Data binding - prevent to select next row after deleting selected row

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a dataTable which is used by a combobox. The dataTable has 3 rows (x, y,z). In the combobox I select the second item (y). After that, I delete from the dataTable the selected row. The selected row in the combobox is last row (z).

I want the combobox to select the first row (x) or doesn't select anything (if it is possible) after deleting row. What should I do?

I am asking about this because I don't kwow which controls use the datatable.
The combobox is only an example showing what can happen in the worst case.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        dt1 = MakeDT();

        combo1.DataSource = dt1;
        combo1.ValueMember = "Name";
        combo1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        combo1.DisplayMember = "Name2";

        combo2.DataSource =dt1;
        combo2.ValueMember = "Name";
        combo2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        combo2.DisplayMember = "Name2";

        combo1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        combo1.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
    private DataTable MakeDT()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("Name2");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        object[] p0 = { "Name0", "0" };
        object[] p1 = { "Name1", "1" };
        object[] p2 = { "Name2", "2" };
        object[] p3 = { "Name3", "3" };
        object[] p4 = { "Name4", "4" };
        dt.Rows.Add(p0);
        dt.Rows.Add(p1);
        dt.Rows.Add(p2);
        dt.Rows.Add(p3);
        dt.Rows.Add(p4);
        return dt;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt1.Rows.RemoveAt(1);
    }
}
```

I have a contaner with dataTables and many controls take datasources from this container. When I refresh datatables in the container, datasources in controls refresh also, but I don't want to selecting next to the deleted row.

Comment: Please read [ask] and post your code. Explaining your code is not even near as effective as showing it. Specially when you tag your question with 2 different programming languages.

Comment: post your code what you have tried to solve your problem. we are happy to help you!

Comment: There's no property you can set to make this happen automatically. It probably happens the way it does because that means that the `SelectedIndex` remains the same. To get the behaviour you want, you'll need to write to do it. Given that you must be deleting the item in code anyway, that should not be a problem. Go ahead and do that and you can then post a proper question if you encounter a specific issue when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This will make them selected index to -1 and if its your requirement, then you can check on button press if the selectedindex is -1 then do something else rather than deleting the combo result.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        comboBox1.Refresh();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: The code was only an example. I lost information about which controls use datatable. Ok, maybe the only way to prevent this behavior, is the container remember (with datatables) remember connected controls. I hoped it could be simpler.

Comment: From your question it seems like you want to prevent the selection of next value after you delete something from the datatable which is connected to the combobox. The code I posted does that exactly.